only want to index the text content of the login page
I have a login page with text content but i only want to index the text content of that page. So which tag should i use for this?
Suppose i have a page abc.com/xyz/life-hack and this page has text content and table. user can see the table after the login. So i want that google only index the text content not he login table.
i had tried only noindex tag but this tag is not helpful for me.

There is no tag or something to do that.
Noindex will prevent indexing the whole page.
So maybe build two pages (one for the text content and one for the login).
You can try to do some javascript magic like "show the login only if visitor is not a bot". But that won´t be very reliable and may lead to google penalties, because of cloaking.
Greets
